# How To Do JavaScript Object Oriented Programming client side The Right Way?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, sequelize.js

I'm doing an API using React, SQL and Sequelize. I'm already finished but now I was asked to do my API request using JavaScript oriented object. The problem is, I don't really know how to do it, and I don't really understand my errors.

This is the class I am trying to do:

### API class

```
class Api {
    constructor(hostName, token) {
            this.hostName = hostName
            this.token = token
    }

    async getPost() {
        return await fetch('api/post/')
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error(res.statusText + "-" + res.url);
            }
            return res;
        })
        .then(post => {
            console.log(post)
            return post
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Page non trouvée")
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}

export const apiRequest = new Api();
```

### Axios config

```
import axios from 'axios';

class AxiosConfig {
  constructor() {
    this.axios = axios.create();
    this.axios.defaults.baseURL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`;
    this.axios.defaults.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    //All request will wait 2 seconds before timeout
    this.axios.defaults.timeout = 2000;
    this.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  }

  GET = async (url) => {
    return await this.axios.get(`/${url}`);
  }

  POST = async (url, payload) => {
    return await this.axios.post(`/${url}`, payload);
  }

  PUT = async (url, payload) => {
    return await this.axios.put(`/${url}`, payload);
  }

  DELETE = async (url) => {
    return await this.axios.delete(`/${url}`);
  }
}

export const axiosInstance = new AxiosConfig();
```

HandlePost() is the function I'm tring to put in oriented object

### NewPostForm

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from '../../UserContext';
import { apiRequest } from '../../utils/api';
import { axiosInstance } from '../../utils/AxiosConfig'
import landscape from './../../assets/icons/landscape.svg'

const NewPostForm = () => {
    const uid =  useContext(UserContext)
    const [userPicture, setUserPicture] = useState('')
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [postPicture, setPostPicture] = useState('')
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUserInfo = async () => {
            if (uid !== null) {
                const userId = uid.userId
                await axiosInstance.GET (`api/auth/${userId}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    setFirstName(res.data.firstName)
                    setLastName(res.data.lastName)
                    setUserPicture(res.data.profile)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        }
        getUserInfo()

    }, [uid, firstName, lastName])


    console.log('parfait', axiosInstance.GET(`api/post`)) // old one, works perfectly
    console.log('objectif', apiRequest.getPost()) // new one, not getting the object I need
    // console.log(axiosInstance.GET(apiRequest.getPost`${uid.userId}`)) // error

    const handlePost = async () => {
        if (message || postPicture) {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append("UserId", uid.userId);
            data.append("content", message);
            if (file) {
                data.append("image", file);
            }

            try {
                const res = await axiosInstance.POST(`api/post`, data);
                console.log('File uploaded', res.data);
                // window.location = '/'
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Failed to upload file', err);
            }
            cancelPost()
        } else {
            alert("Veuillez entrer un message")
        }
    }

    const handlePicture = (e) => {
        setPostPicture(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
        setFile(e.target.files[0])
    }

    const cancelPost = () => {
        setMessage('')
        setPostPicture('')
        setFile('')
    }

    return (
        <form className='post-container' >
            <h2 className='h1'>Créer un post</h2>
            <NavLink to="/profile">
                <figure title='Profil utilisateur' className='new card-header'>
                    <img className='nav-profile' src={userPicture ? userPicture : "./images/img/profile.png"} width='50px' alt="profil de l'utilisateur" />
                    <h3 className='h2'>{firstName} {lastName}</h3>
                </figure>
            </NavLink>
            <div className='post-form'>
                <textarea
                    type="text"
                    name="message"
                    id="message"
                    cols="50"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="Quoi de neuf ?"
                    onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                    value={message}
                ></textarea>
                {postPicture && <img src={postPicture} alt="preview" className="img-preview" />}
            </div>

            <div className='footer-form'>
                <div className='icon'>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        id='file-upload'
                        name='file'
                        accept='.jpg, .jpeg, .png'
                        onChange={(e) => handlePicture(e)}
                    />
                    <label className='file-input__label' htmlFor="file-upload">
                        <img className='svg' src={landscape} alt="upload icone paysage" />
                        Ajouter une l'image
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className='new button-container'>
                    {message || postPicture ? (
                        <button className='new cancel-btn' onClick={(e) => cancelPost()}>Annuler</button>
                    ) : null}
                    <button className='new validate-btn' onClick={(e) => handlePost()}>Envoyer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default NewPostForm;
```

[image: console.log results]

My first console.log() returning the object that I need, when the second (supposed oriented object one) doesn't. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and the documentation doesn't help, I don't have the "good" questions.

Thanks

EDIT :

```
class Api {
    constructor(hostName, token) {
            this.hostName = hostName
            this.token = token
    }

    async getPost() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('api/post')
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error(res.statusText + "-" + res.url);
            }
            return await res.json();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Page non trouvée")
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}

export const apiRequest = new Api();
```

[image: promise result: undefined]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the code that how you used `fetch` method. This is from the documentation.

> The Response object, in turn, does not directly contain the actual JSON response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, we use the json() method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.

You have to update your `getPost` method like below.

```
async getPost() {
    return await fetch('api/post/').then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.statusText + "-" + res.url);
        }
        return res.json();
    }).then(post => {
        console.log(post)
        return post
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Page non trouvée")
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

You already using `async` and `await` so you don't need to use `.then`. The code can be updated like below.

```
async getPost() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('api/post/')
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.statusText + "-" + res.url);
        }
        return await res.json();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Page non trouvée")
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mchowdam. I update my getPost like you said but  now I'm going straigth to the .catch part, and instead of an "object", I got undefined.

Comment: I have edited the answer. You already using `await`.

Comment: I edit my getPost but nothing change. I also edit my question, you can now see my console.log answer. Thank for your help

Comment: You got an error, that is the reason the `catch` got executed. Check whether your API is giving the correct response or not.

Comment: Before I was trying oriented object, everything worked perfectly fine. The answer was, in that case, my posts list, now I've got nothing. I add headers:{"Content-type":"application/json"} but it threw me an error